# What are possible values of $y$ if $|y| \leq 1$?

Tags: inequality

Would it have 2 possible values?

**Possibility 1:**

```
y ≤ 1   
y ≤ 1, 0, -1, -2...
```

**Possibility 2:**

```
-y ≤ 1
```

To get value of y, I multiply both sides by -1, so sign will reverse, *right?*

```
y ≥ -1
```

So, the possible values of y would be **-1, 0 and 1?**

**Is this correct?**

Comment: All possible values are $$-1\le y \le 1$$

Comment: You assume that $y$ is an integer. Is it the case ?

Answer (score 1):

In essence, you simply need that $$|y|=|-y|$$.
Therefore $|y|\le1$ implies $y\le 1$ or $-y\le1 \to y\ge-1$.

So:  $$y \ge -1 \text { and } y \le 1 \to -1\le y\le 1$$